find unique record from table
Consider the following table:
Table Name: IN_OUT_RECORD
Query:
select DISTINCT  * 
from IN_OUT_RECORD AD 
where (AD_USER_ID = 'ST1301220007') 
AND (AD.AD_DATE BETWEEN '2024-06-01 00:00:00' AND ('2024-06-12 23:59:00'));




AD_ID
AD_USER_ID
AD_STATUS
AD_DATE




11277
ST1301220007
IN
2024-06-01 09:10:40


11278
ST1301220007
OUT
2024-06-01 09:10:55


11279
ST1301220007
IN
2024-06-01 09:10:56


11280
ST1301220007
OUT
2024-06-01 18:21:23


11281
ST1301220007
IN
2024-06-05 09:20:21


11282
ST1301220007
OUT
2024-06-05 19:05:22


11283
ST1301220007
IN
2024-06-07 09:05:25


11284
ST1301220007
OUT
2024-06-07 18:05:25


11285
ST1301220007
IN
2024-06-07 18:06:25


11286
ST1301220007
OUT
2024-06-08 09:10:56


11287
ST1301220007
IN
2024-06-08 09:11:50



from here I want to retrieve only a single IN and OUT in a day.
for example:



AD_ID
AD_USER_ID
AD_STATUS
AD_DATE




11277
ST1301220007
IN
2024-06-01 09:10:40


11280
ST1301220007
OUT
2024-06-01 18:21:23


11281
ST1301220007
IN
2024-06-05 09:20:21


11282
ST1301220007
OUT
2024-06-05 19:05:22


11283
ST1301220007
IN
2024-06-07 09:05:25


11284
ST1301220007
OUT
2024-06-07 18:05:25


11287
ST1301220007
IN
2024-06-08 09:11:50



Please help me to get the Correct Query.

I.e. select rows with IN where not exists the row with lower datatime and IN for the same day, then select rows with OUT where not exists the row with greater datatime and OUT for the same day, and finally UNION them. For OUT additionally check that IN with lower datetime for the same day exists. The task is not hard.

another solution can be

first find the minimum, and maximum, values per date:

SELECT 
    r1.AD_USER_ID, 
    DATE(r1.AD_DATE) d,
    MIN(CASE WHEN r1.AD_STATUS='IN' THEN AD_DATE END) as min_date,
    MAX(CASE WHEN r1.AD_STATUS='OUT' THEN AD_DATE END) as max_date
  FROM records r1
  WHERE r1.AD_USER_ID = 'ST1301220007' 
  GROUP BY r1.AD_USER_ID, DATE(r1.AD_DATE)




AD_USER_ID
d
min_date
max_date




ST1301220007
2024-06-01
2024-06-01 09:10:40
2024-06-01 18:21:23


ST1301220007
2024-06-05
2024-06-05 09:20:21
2024-06-05 19:05:22


ST1301220007
2024-06-07
2024-06-07 09:05:25
2024-06-07 18:05:25


ST1301220007
2024-06-08
2024-06-08 09:11:50
2024-06-08 09:10:56




Then do the UNION ALL to find the needed records:

WITH cte AS (
  SELECT 
    r1.AD_USER_ID, 
    DATE(r1.AD_DATE) d,
    MIN(CASE WHEN r1.AD_STATUS='IN' THEN AD_DATE END) as min_date,
    MAX(CASE WHEN r1.AD_STATUS='OUT' THEN AD_DATE END) as max_date
  FROM records r1
  WHERE r1.AD_USER_ID = 'ST1301220007' 
  GROUP BY r1.AD_USER_ID, DATE(r1.AD_DATE)
)
SELECT r1.AD_ID, r1.AD_USER_ID, r1.AD_STATUS, r1.AD_DATE
FROM records r1
INNER JOIN cte ON cte.AD_USER_ID = r1.AD_USER_ID 
              and cte.min_date = r1.AD_DATE
              and r1.AD_STATUS = 'IN'
UNION ALL
SELECT r1.AD_ID, r1.AD_USER_ID, r1.AD_STATUS, r1.AD_DATE
FROM records r1
INNER JOIN cte ON cte.AD_USER_ID = r1.AD_USER_ID 
              and cte.max_date = r1.AD_DATE and cte.max_date > cte.min_date
              and r1.AD_STATUS = 'OUT'
ORDER BY AD_ID

output:



AD_ID
AD_USER_ID
AD_STATUS
AD_DATE




11277
ST1301220007
IN
2024-06-01 09:10:40


11280
ST1301220007
OUT
2024-06-01 18:21:23


11281
ST1301220007
IN
2024-06-05 09:20:21


11282
ST1301220007
OUT
2024-06-05 19:05:22


11283
ST1301220007
IN
2024-06-07 09:05:25


11284
ST1301220007
OUT
2024-06-07 18:05:25


11287
ST1301220007
IN
2024-06-08 09:11:50



DBFIDDLE: https://dbfiddle.uk/q2o-QFZO

As you seem to want to perserve the AD_ID, this is a bit trickier than a simple GROUP BY and UNION.
You will need indicators which AD_DATE for AD_STATUS 'IN' is the first one, and which AD_DATE for AD_STATUS 'OUT' is the last one, per day.
We can make these indicators this by using ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY .. ORDER BY ..). To partition by day, use the DATE() function to disregard the time.
After this, you can select the relevant IN and OUT records per day, and UNION them, and potentially sort them by USER_AD, DATE(AD_DATE) and AD_STATUS.
I will use some cte's to show these steps:
WITH status_per_day AS (
  SELECT 
    records.*,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY AD_USER_ID, AD_STATUS, DATE(AD_DATE) 
      ORDER BY AD_DATE ASC) AS first_time,  
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY AD_USER_ID, AD_STATUS, DATE(AD_DATE) 
      ORDER BY AD_DATE DESC) AS last_time
  FROM records
), 

unioned_statuses AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM status_per_day
  WHERE AD_STATUS = 'IN' 
  AND first_time = 1
  UNION 
  SELECT *
  FROM status_per_day
  WHERE AD_STATUS = 'OUT' 
  AND last_time = 1
)
  
SELECT AD_ID, AD_USER_ID, AD_STATUS, AD_DATE
FROM unioned_statuses
ORDER BY AD_USER_ID, DATE(AD_DATE), AD_STATUS

db<>fiddle here

Do you see excess row id=11286 in your fiddle output?

Given the problem description 11286 should actually be in the output. I'm guessing OP forgot to put it in his desired output.

Not sure why this needs a UNION you can select straight out of the first CTE with OR conditions.

Not matched with actual answer. still showing data 11286 ST1301220007 OUT 2024-06-08 09:10:56

It may be happened, if someone forgot to punch card at entry time.

It's going to be a bit more efficient than the other answer, if you keep the same ORDER BY clauses in the two window functions. You can hack LEAD to find if you are on the last row.
WITH status_per_day AS (
  SELECT 
    records.*,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY AD_USER_ID, DATE(AD_DATE), AD_STATUS 
      ORDER BY AD_DATE) AS rn,  
    LEAD(1) OVER (
      PARTITION BY AD_USER_ID, DATE(AD_DATE), AD_STATUS
      ORDER BY AD_DATE) AS is_not_last,
    MIN(CASE WHEN AD_STATUS = 'IN' THEN AD_DATE END) OVER (
      PARTITION BY AD_USER_ID, DATE(AD_DATE)) AS min_in_date
  FROM records
)  
SELECT AD_ID, AD_USER_ID, AD_STATUS, AD_DATE
FROM status_per_day
WHERE (
  AD_STATUS = 'IN' AND rn = 1
  OR
  AD_STATUS = 'OUT' AND is_not_last IS NULL AND min_in_date < AD_DATE
)
ORDER BY
  AD_USER_ID,
  DATE(AD_DATE),
  AD_STATUS;

db<>fiddle

Not matched with actual answer. still showing data 11286 ST1301220007 OUT 2024-06-08 09:10:56

It may be happened, if someone forgot to punch card at entry time.

Then I don't understand the logic you will need to be clearer.

You are in office/college and punching card multiple times for entry & exit. For some reason sometimes entry or exit time may not be locked for system issue or for other issue. In that scenario, you code will not work. Check actual output & your outut

OK I think I understand. You just need to do a conditional window function to get the earliest IN and check it's less than the current OUT.

Yes, @Charlieface I added my answer according to that

It's a causes of headache.
There is a record where first out and then in time.

If you run this section:
WITH t1 AS (
select *,
    CASE WHEN(ad_status = 'IN') THEN
        MIN(ad_date) OVER (PARTITION BY cast(ad_date as date), ad_user_id, ad_status = 'IN')
    END AS MIN_IN,
    CASE WHEN(ad_status = 'OUT') THEN
        MAX(ad_date) OVER (PARTITION BY cast(ad_date as date), ad_user_id, ad_status = 'OUT')
    END AS MAX_OUT
from IN_OUT_RECORD
),
base_table as (
    SELECT * FROM t1
    WHERE (ad_status = 'IN' AND ad_date = MIN_IN)
    OR (ad_status = 'OUT' AND ad_date = MAX_OUT)
)
select * from base_table order by cast(ad_date as date);

You get output like:

So, same issue is arriving here.
For that reason, 
    first you have to split that table into two section 
    and then you have compare the entry and exit time.
So, your next code is:
base_table2 as (
select bin.ad_user_id,
    bin.ad_date,
    bin.ad_status as in_status, 
    bout.ad_status as out_status,
   --  bin.MIN_IN,
   --  bout.MAX_OUT,
    CASE 
        WHEN(LEAST(bin.MIN_IN, bout.MAX_OUT) = bin.MIN_IN) THEN bin.MIN_IN
        WHEN(GREATEST(bin.MIN_IN, bout.MAX_OUT) = bin.MIN_IN) THEN bin.MIN_IN
    END as entry_time,
    CASE 
        WHEN(GREATEST(bin.MIN_IN, bout.MAX_OUT) = bout.MAX_OUT) THEN bout.MAX_OUT 
        WHEN(LEAST(bin.MIN_IN, bout.MAX_OUT) = bout.MAX_OUT) THEN NULL
    END as exit_time
from       (select * from base_table where ad_status = 'IN')  bin
left join  (select * from base_table where ad_status = 'OUT') bout
on bin.ad_user_id = bout.ad_user_id
AND cast(bin.ad_date as date) = cast(bout.ad_date as date)
)
select * from base_table2

Which give you output like:

Next, compare this table with your base table and query is:
select c1.*
from IN_OUT_RECORD c1
INNER JOIN base_table2 c2
on c1.ad_user_id = c1.ad_user_id
and ( 
   (c1.ad_status = 'IN' and c1.ad_date = c2.entry_time)
   OR
   (c1.ad_status = 'OUT' and c1.ad_date = c2.exit_time)
)
order by c1.ad_date;

Which gives your final table according to your output:

This is code: db<>fiddle
But, there are some possible scenario will happened as follows:

entry time exists but no exit time
no entry time but exit time exists

That will not handle here.
If you want to apply that logic update the base_table2 creation accordingly
It's a good question, make little time to solve.
I hope this will resolve query according to description.
